# Edit is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord, discord.js, frameworks

Trying to make a discord bot that will send a message to a specific channel on startup. I have the message sent to the specific channel on startup, however, when I try to edit it a error is thrown saying `message.edit` is not a function. I am following the direct steps from the documentation and it is not working. Why and how do I fix this issue?

```
let message: any;

    if (isTextChannel(channel) && !isStageChannel(channel)) {
           message = channel.send({ embeds: [ playerCountEmbedLoading() ] });
    }

    setInterval(() => {

    if (isTextChannel(channel) && !isStageChannel(channel)) {
           return message.edit({ embeds: [ playerCountEmbed() ] })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not awaiting the promise returned from sending the message.

```js
message = await channel.send({ embeds: [ playerCountEmbedLoading() ] });
```

[Source](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/stable/src/structures/interfaces/TextBasedChannel.js#L114)
[Documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send)

Comment: This did not work

Comment: Does the error persist? Or is there a new one? Are you sure you recompiled the typescript?

Answer (score 0):

You should do type checking before defining the message. In this example I will use a typegaurd to filter out non text based channels.

Also, `Channel.send()` returns a promise containing the sent message. You need to await the promise.

```
import { ChannelTypes } from "discord.js";

if (channel.type !== ChannelTypes.GuildText) return console.warn("Channel is not a text channel");
 
let message = await channel.send({ embeds: [ playerCountEmbedLoading() ] });

setInterval(async() => {
   try {
      await message.edit({ embeds: [ playerCountEmbed() ] })
   } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
   }
}, ...);
```

Lastly, why use TypeScript if you're going to type a variable as `any` when you know exactly what it needs to be? Take advantage of the language you utilize by typing your variables.

```
import type { Message } from "discord.js";
 
let message: Message;
```